# Can a F1 visa(expired) applicant apply for Canada visa from USA?

Tags: usa, visa, canada

My F-1 student visa is already expired this year(June, 2018) and I am currently working on my OPT's STEM Extension work authorization, which expires by May 2019. My current employer has sponsored my H-1B visa for the year 2019 and it was picked in the lottery process and recently I have received the "Request for Additional Evidence".

The point here is, I am not sure whether I would get the H-1B approval or not, so thinking to have a Plan-B to stay in the USA or at least go to Canada to work for like 5 years before going back to my Home country.

What is the procedure for me(considering my current situation) to get a Canadian visa(working)? Can I apply it from here(USA) without travelling back to my Home country? Required documentation would be really helpful. Are there any other viable options for me to stay in USA legally and continue my work without pursuing another degree/marrying some citizen?

**Note:** I do have one more opportunity to get sponsored for H-1B for next year, but considering my OPT STEM expires by May 1st week, that is like trying to hit a fast moving Plane(at cruising altitudes) from the top of the Burj Khalifa.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In general, you're supposed to apply for visas from your place of residence, which is the US, so traveling to your home country would not be recommended.  Some countries require that you show your legal presence in the place where you're applying (I don't know if Canada does), but your visa having expired does not make your presence illegal, and Canadian consular officials in the US will know that.